# Execute code in a sandbox, with modules in same context

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm automating running the ECMA-402 [test suite](https://github.com/tc39/test262/tree/master/test/suite/intl402) against the `Intl` polyfill I wrote, and I've hit some problems.  Currently, the tests are run against a fully-built version of the library, which means having to recompile every time a change is made before the tests can run.  I'm trying to improve it by splitting the code up into separate modules and using require to run the tests.

The main problem comes into focus when I try and run the tests using the `vm` module.  If I add the polyfill to the test's sandbox, some of the tests fail when checking native behaviour — the polyfill's objects don't inherit from the test context's `Object.prototype`, for example.  Passing `require` to the tests will not work because the modules are still compiled and executed in the parent's context.

The easiest solution in my head was to spawn a new node process and write the code to the process's `stdin`, but the spawned `node` process doesn't execute the code written to it and just waits around forever.  This is the code I tried:

```
function runTest(testPath, cb) {
    var test,
        err = '',
        content = 'var IntlPolyfill = require("' + LIB_PATH + '");\n';

    content += LIBS.fs.readFileSync(LIBS.path.resolve(TEST_DIR, testPath)).toString();
    content += 'runner();';

    test = LIBS.spawn(process.execPath, process.execArgv);
    test.stdin.write(content, 'utf8');

    // cb runs the next test
    test.on('exit', cb);
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why Node.js doesn't execute the code written to its `stdin` stream, or if there's another way I can get the module to compile in the same context as the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I chose to use the `-e` command line switch to pass the code directly to the new node instance.  It only took a slight modification to the code:

```
function runTest(testPath, cb) {
    var test,
        err = '',
        content = 'var IntlPolyfill = require("' + LIB_PATH + '");\n';

    content += LIBS.fs.readFileSync(LIBS.path.resolve(TEST_DIR, testPath)).toString();
    content += 'runner();';

    test = LIBS.spawn(process.execPath, process.execArgv.concat('-e', content));

    // cb runs the next test
    test.on('exit', cb);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must close the stdin for the child process to consume data and exit. Do this when you are done passing code.

```
test.stdin.end();
```

Comment: I tried this initially, but the `node` process ended immediately without evaluating the code (aka running the test).

Comment: @AndyE did you output the test results to stdout? Did the test execute and exit or it did not execute.

Comment: the test didn't execute, they throw errors and I was checking the exit code as well as `stderr`.  I did manage to work around it, however, and passed the code as an argv along with the `-e` switch.